# Z-index conflict on overlapping divs

Tags: css

A bit of a 'sweat' - I have come across a first issue with Z-index that only affects FF and works fine in IE. I have 2 horizontal divs that overlap each other and take almost 100% width both. There is a side bar on the left in one div and a scrollbar on the right in a second div. Both have the same Z-index and when I press on othe left bar in IE it activates the links and when I press the scrollbar on the right it works fine. BUT in FF - it's not working. So either I have to set higher index on a left div and then I won't access the right or the other way round. I need to use both and thing is I cannot really change the divs. Is there any resolution to this ? I've tried javascript Z-index shifting but doesn't work smooth...Thanks.

```
#left_bar { 
position: relative;
margin-top:-112px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;


}

#post_table { // THE SCROLL on the right
position: relative;
margin-top:-800px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-left:182px;
left:-12px;






}

#bar_links { 
// THE LINKS on the left
position: relative;
margin-left:18px;
margin-right: auto;
padding-right:700px;
width: auto;
top:180px;


}
HTML:

<div align="center" id="left_bar" style="white-space:nowrap">
<img src="images/posting.png"/></div>
<div align="center" id="bar_links">    
<a href="javascript:;" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" 
onmouseover="MM_swapImage('images/slices/lipstick1','','images/slices/lipstick2.png',1);">
<img name="images/slices/lipstick1"src="images/slices/lipstick1.png" 
width="132" height="56" border="0" id="lipstick" /></a>
</div>
<div align="center" id="post_table" style="height: 730px; width:644px; overflow: auto;overflow-    x:hidden;">
<table width="640" id="table_main">
<tr>
<td>    

<?php 

echo "<table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' border='0' width='600' align='center'   
id='inner_table'><tr><td>";
    echo "<span style='font-size:11px;color:#dddddd;white-space:nowrap;background-  
image: url(images/branches.png);float:left'>&nbsp;".$post_date."&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;";
    echo "</td></tr><br/>";
    echo "<tr><td align='left' id='post_style'>";
    echo  $posting;
    echo "</tr></td>";
    }; ?>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: could you add example to fiddler?

Comment: Could you provide code, or - even better - jsfiddle demo?

Comment: ..or maybe I used not efficient javascripting for Z-index swapping..

Comment: oh man, you use CSS and `style` attribute + `align, width, height` attributes - it's hard to fallow all rules.

Comment: Yes, exactly..I know it was probably wrongly arranged from the beginning - but the reason was to use .png transparent pics and implement links and code inside them plus position them in the centre / center...and it came up like that after many modifications...the thing is too late for changing the whole code I think..I just wonder why it works fine in IE with the same Z-index...and not in FF.

Comment: Chances are it is something wrong in your code if it works in one browser and not the other - how does Safari and Chrome respond? FF does have slightly different handling than IE in regards to the z-index (IE is usually more forgiving for once). However, since your code is a mix of External CSS, inline CSS, HTML, JavaScript and PHP I would recommend posting a link to somewhere people can have a look at your issue first hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can certainly say is that you are almost certain to have issue : Your HTML is not valid at all.

This line alone will do different thing in different browser :

```
echo "</td></tr><br/>";
```

Second, you speak about a **z-index problem**, but there is **none** in the code you supplied. How can we fix something that doesn't exist?

Your problem is certainly that `$posting;` is not displayed in FF but it is in IE. The reason is quite simple : Your `#post_table` is defined **after** `#left_bar` and `#bar_links`. It is why it appears **under** them.

I have no idea what is your idea, but I can confirm you that using **lots** of **negatives margins** will be hard to manage. Right now you define 2 box and move a third one **over/under** them...

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUfGr/) using your somewhat corrected+adapted code that look similar in FF and IE.

## You should start by rethinking your layout... And learning proper HTML and CSS.

Comment: First - the code renders perfect in most browsers - this is the answer to HTML not being valid...The PHP tag including table tags renders fine.Second, yes there is no z-index in the code and I explained why in my question. Simply because if I add any z-index the div layer will come on top of another. You SHOULD know that if there is no z-index in the code the browsers stack divs according to their order in the HTML. And the orders are fine - the problem arises when you want to escalate 'bar_links' over 'post_table' or the other way round. The code involves PHP and such is the nature of it..

Comment: P.S. I admit the code should've been better structured - but I used lots of relative .png images and that's why the issue about it. I've just validated the code in 'DW' - it doesn't show a single error apart from a small javascript oncontextmenu command.

Comment: `post_table` is defined _after_ `bar_links`. It's why most browser will put `bar_links` _under_ `post_table`. Don't call a z-index problem when there's no z-index : Call it a superposition issue or whatever. DW(Dreamweaver I suppose) won't validate your code except for the syntax. Use some service like [w3c](http://validator.w3.org/). And lastly, to get rid of the php, open your page in a browser, display it's source, and show us that (or throw it in a pastebin/jsfiddle). I'd really like to help you more on the issue, but right now I have my hands tied by the incomplete source you provide.

Comment: P.S. (2) I also corrected / eradicated the amount of unecessary negative margins..thanks..

Comment: I've [updated the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUfGr/3/) so that it would be sane/usable (no images make it hard to toy it). I removed all negative margin except one on `#post_table` to show you what happen. Your table is put under the `left_bar`. I also corrected your tons of table error... (it's <tr><td>..</t__d__></t__r__>). Do you still see your error or it's too modified?

Comment: Thanks, I can see from the fiddle - the 'bar_links' extends far on the right and overlaps the right side of the bar where the scroll is ( the left_bar spans all the width ) this is the issue, you see ? Thanks for the modification - I'll take a deeper look into it in a sec. The 'left_bar' is just called left - but in fact it is the .png image that spans almost all the width and onto which I placed a table with a scrollbar on the right..

Comment: P.S. the problem was to clip the width of the 'bar_links' to prevent overlapping onto the right side - but when I tried - the 'bar_links' lost its relative width in the browser resize you see...

Comment: Thanks Kraz - I think I've worked it out at last - it works fine now. I need to get down to CSS books for real...here's the fix: `#bar_links{
position: relative;
left:-340px;
top:280px;
z-index:2;
width:840px;


}` The issue with FF was the 'padding' that masked the 'post_table' Thanks a lot for your comments / help...'till next time.